# ResNet34 - Pretrained model on imagenet using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, resnet, imagenet

Can someone point me to the `Resnet34` pre-trained model on image-net using tensorflow? I am not sure but TF-slim trained model are same or would there be difference?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Keras ResNet(18,34,50,101,152) pre-trained models https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models